# Is there anywhere to legally download Windows 8 Pro System Builder 64bit ISO?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I want to build a Win8 VM on my MBA, but can't find anywhere to download this OS...

Comment: Sure, MSDN. But MSDN subscriptions aren't free.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an article [here](http://www.intowindows.com/download-windows-8-iso-from-microsoft-using-product-key/) that tells you how to get the ISO. The thing about this article is that you have to have a product key. Thus you aren't able to get out of buying it.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft usually only sells "OEM System Builder" licences to vendors, in bulk; You basically can't buy just one, and "general public" isn't meant to buy them at all.

This licence also does not allow for installing on a VM.

You can buy a non-OEM licence and download the image directly from MS site.

Comment: You haven't kept up with the times. There is no "full retail" version anymore with Win8. If you don't want to Upgrade from a previous version, the only way to install Win8 on a new PC is via the **System Builder** version, which *is* available to end users and single copies *are* available. Also, if you're not an OEM then Win8 System Builder's **Personal Use Licence** applies to you, which *does* allow installation in a VM (however each copy, physical or virtual, needs a separate key obviously).