# Windows 8 Professional Download

Tags: windows, windows-8, legal

I have a product key. I am not on Windows. I would love to use http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only, but it requires me to be on windows. How can I get a non-cracked windows ISO?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This question is off topic here. Please see [here](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) for an explanation of what kinds of questions are on-topic and [here](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask) for a list of subjects that are explicitly off-topic. Our guidelines for asking good questions are [here](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you don't already own Windows, you cannot legally install/use an "Upgrade" edition. Also, not any key will work with any installation. There are Retail keys, OEM keys, TechNet keys, and MSDN keys (to name a few).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there anywhere to legally download Windows 8 Pro System Builder 64bit ISO?](http://superuser.com/questions/563131/is-there-anywhere-to-legally-download-windows-8-pro-system-builder-64bit-iso)

Answer (score 0):

I have been in the same situation as you have and I'm afraid I was not able to find a feasible way of doing this (at least not legally). I ended up needing to install my copy of Windows 7 and run the upgrade wizard provided by Microsoft.

That being said it is possible to get an installation disc for Windows 8 which commonly comes with other Windows 8 systems provided by the manufacturer however finding one of these can be tricky at best.